# Merging two lists into on ordered in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Given two lists: L1 = [1,3,5] and L2 = [1,2,4], I need to write code to merge them in sorted order, so the result would be L3 = [1,1,2,3,4,5] w/o using `cut operator` or `fail`. I'm getting familiar with Prolog and Im not sure how to approach this problem. Could anybody please tell me how to solve this? I've starting like the following but got stuck for awhile:

```
merge([], [], []).
merge([], L, L).
merge(L, [], L).
merge([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [L|Rest]:-
    H1 =< H2 -> L = merge(H1
```

Comment: It looks as if parts of your question are missing... how about editing your question and adding these parts?

Answer (score 2):

The traditional way to do this is to use `compare/3`. When evaluated, it binds its first argument to `<`, `=`, or `>`. You can then use this value as the first argument of an auxiliary predicate:

```
...
compare(Order, X, Y),
merge_aux(Order, X, Y, Xs, Ys, Merged).

merge_aux(<, X, Y, ...
merge_aux(=, X, Y, ...
merge_aux(>, X, Y, ...
```

The call to `compare/3` is deterministic, and so is the call to `merge_aux`, so you don't really need cuts at any point.

Comment: But `compare/3` is like `(@<)/2` and the like and not like `(=<)/2` which evaluates the arguments.

Comment: @false yes. At no point does OP specify if the lists are strictly integers, or numbers, or arithmetic expressions, or ground terms, or any terms, possibly variables. `compare/3` is not good enough only for arithmetic expressions, rational numbers, or variables.

Comment: OP gives `(=<)/2` knowingly or not :-). But what is so nice with `(=<)/2` is that it produces an instantiation-error for all the nasty cases.

Comment: @false ... and works on nothing but numbers/arithmetic expressions

Comment: @false to be clear, if we decided to take the question at face value, then we could say, "well, why not `merge([1,3,5], [1,2,4], [1,1,2,3,4,5]).` This contains no cuts, `fail`, and is deterministic". I really dislike badly specified questions, as they are impossible to really answer. I have written bad questions too, btw.

Comment: @Boris. Haha, only serious:  Recently, some of my Prolog students got stuck solving some problem and wrote code *just like that*... I could convince them easily, however, that this road means **a lot** of work:)

Comment: @repeat I had the unbelievable luck to have an interesting job while studying computer science. I was able to make the following observation: because in university we have to be graded (fairly), the assignments we get usually have "correct" answers, and the problem statements are fairly detailed. Problems I had to solve at my job had did not have correct answers, yet, because _understanding and defining the problem_ was the real work. There is no right or wrong until figuring out what it is we are after.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it declaratively, what you want to describe is a merge that consists of two appended lists that are sorted. You can divide this into 2 subtasks: One appending the lists and another sorting the resulting list. Using the predicate append/3 from library(lists) and the built-in predicate msort/2 you can directly put down this idea in prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

merge(L1,L2,L3) :-
    append(L1,L2,X),
    msort(X,L3).

?- merge([1,3,5],[1,2,4],L).
L = [1,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this just with recursive calls you can try the below, I figure it is probably possible to do it more efficiently. The first recursive clause specifies what to do if the head of List X is greater than the head of List Y, the second recursive clause vice-versa. This will deal with lists of different lengths.

I am working on a merge sort so now need to work out the rest. Next step how to chop a list in half!

```
merge_ordered_lists([], [], []).
merge_ordered_lists(Xs, [], Xs).
merge_ordered_lists([], Ys, Ys).
merge_ordered_lists([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [X|Rs]) :-
    X =< Y,
    merge_ordered_lists(Xs, [Y|Ys], Rs).
merge_ordered_lists([X|Xs],[Y|Ys], [Y|Rs]) :-
    X > Y,
    merge_ordered_lists([X|Xs], Ys, Rs).
```

Comment: `?- merge_ordered_lists([], [], []).` succeeds thrice!